# SQL Selecting count from join returning 0 instead of null result

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a query that gets data and also joins another table (A) and counts the rows in that join table (B). However if the main table (A) is empty I want the query to return nothing. However it is returning a result of null for id and date and an integer value of 0 for users instead of a null row. How do I get an empty result instead of it returning something?

Returning:

```
id   | date | users
null | null | 0
```

SQL Code

```
SELECT
    `sessions`.`id`,
    `sessions`.`date`,
    COUNT( sessions_users.id ) AS users 
FROM
    `sessions`
    LEFT JOIN `sessions_users` ON `sessions`.`id` = `sessions_users`.`sessions_id`
```

Answer (score 1):

An aggregate query without a `group by` clause *always* returns a single record, regardless of the content of the underlying result set (and even if it is empty).

But, since you have non-aggregated columns in the `select` clause (`sessions.id` and `sessions.date`), your query is missing a `group by` clause anyway. In non-ancient versions in MySQL, where sql mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is enabled by default, this is a syntax error.

Consider:

```
SELECT
    `sessions`.`id`,
    `sessions`.`date`,
    COUNT( sessions_users.id ) AS users 
FROM
    `sessions`
    LEFT JOIN `sessions_users` ON `sessions`.`id` = `sessions_users`.`sessions_id`
GROUP BY
    `sessions`.`id`,
    `sessions`.`date`
```

This will produce one record per session id and date, along with the count of matching records in `sessions_users`. If there are no records in `sessions`, the query will return an empty result set.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, instead of `NULL`, you want something like this:

```
id   | date | users
     |      | 0
```

If so, just simply use `IFNULL()` in your `SELECT` as such:

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(`sessions`.`id`,' ') as id,
    IFNULL(`sessions`.`date`,' ') as date,
....
```

There are also a few other ways to achieve this using just `IF()` or `CASE ..` but `IFNULL` is very straight forward.

BUT if you don't want to see any `NULL` and `0` values, change your `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like you want an inner join:

```
SELECT s.id, s.date, COUNT(*) as users
FROM sessions s JOIN
     sessions_users su
     ON su.id = su.sessions_id;
```